# SQL запросы PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Делаю ТЗ, в котором одно из заданий SQL запросы. У меня субд отказывается работать, времени на поиск причины и исправление нет. Посмотрите правильно ли сделал?

В для третьего и четвёртого задания формулы: (кол-во users в опред. день/ Все users * 100%) и (кол-во users которые зашли или зайдут / Все users * 100%)

1. SELECT day, COUNT(uid) FROM dailyusers GROUP BY  day;
2. SELECT reg_time, COUNT(uid) FROM users GROUP BY reg_time;
3. SELECT day FROM dailyusers , ((COUNT(uid) FROM dailyusers  * 100) / COUNT(uid) FROM users ) GROUP BY day;
4. Тут я ещё думаю, но как будет готово отредактирую вопрос

[image: Задание из ТЗ]

Comment: К первым двум претензий нет. Третий - логику вообще не понял. Четвёртый запрос должен учитывать, что в разные дни было разное количество зарегистрированных пользователей. PS. В PostgreSQL вообще-то есть оконные функции.

Comment: @Akina Количество узеров за день умножить на 100 и разделить на  количество строк из таблицы users.

Comment: *Количество узеров за день умножить* за КАКОЙ день?

Comment: @Akina умножить за каждый день

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насчёт последнего не уверен. Как ответят, скажу точно

a.  Число активных пользователей в день

```
SELECT day, COUNT (uid) FROM dailyusers GROUP BY day;
```

b.  Число зарегистрированных пользователей в день

```
SELECT reg_time, COUNT (uid) FROM users GROUP BY reg_time;
```

c.  Однодневный классический ретеншн (классическое удержание)

```
SELECT d.day ((COUNT(d.uid)*100)/COUNT(u.uid)) 
FROM dailyusers AS d, users AS u 
WHERE d.date = нужная дата
GROUP BY d.day;
```

d.  Однодневный роллинг ретеншн (скользящее удержание)

```
SELECT ((COUNT(SELECT d.uid FROM dailyusers AS d where заданный день < max(d.day) order by d.day)*100)/COUNT(u.uid)) 
FROM dailyusers AS d, users AS u 
WHERE d.date = нужная дата
GROUP BY day;
```